# Time complexity logarithmic

Tags: java, time, structure, complexity-theory

```
for(i = 1; i < n; i *= 2) {
    sum++;
    for(j = 0; j < n; j += 2)
        total++;
}
```

Time complexity:

```
O(log(n))
O(log(n))
O(n)*O(log(n))
O(n)*O(log(n))
```

So final answer is: `O(log(n))`

Is this correct?

Comment: your code is not clear , first write It in the form that we can recognize which instruction is in which for ? is the second for nested loop ?

Comment: yes it is nested loop

Comment: By this code, no, it is not

Comment: By this code is not !

Comment: if it is nested loop then complexity is O(nlgn)

Comment: if it is not nested time complexity will be O(n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the complexity will be something like this :

```
O(lgN)
    O(1)
    O(N/2) == O(N)
         O(1)
```

so the complexity is :

> this is the final answer O(lgN)*(O(1) + O(N)*O(1))
>
> O(N)*O(1) = O(N) (1)
>
> O(N)+O(1) = O(N) (2) because O(N) is bigger than O(1)
>
> assuming (1) & (2) the final answer will be O(lgN)*O(N) = O(N lgN)

Comment: ohh the          sum++   is not O(logn) because i mean its inside the loop

Comment: Yes, but why if its not nested the answer is O(n) not O(log(n))?

Comment: lgN is the time when you have a survey on N , but it length of survey is log of N , here at each step you are deviding N by 2 , so the complexity is log N to the base 2

Answer (score 1):

The complexity is: O(n) * O(lg(n))